# Linq - 'Saving' OrderBy operation (c#)

Tags: linq, lambda, sql-order-by

Assume I have generic list `L` of some type in c#. Then, using linq, call `OrderBy()` on it, passing in a lambda expression.

If I then re-assign the `L`, the previous order operation will obviously be lost.

Is there any way I can 'save' the lambda expression I used on the list before i reassigned it, and re-apply it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [Func delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151.aspx) to store your ordering then pass that to the OrderBy method:

```
Func<int, int> orderFunc = i => i; // func for ordering
var list = Enumerable.Range(1,10).OrderByDescending(i => i); // 10, 9 ... 1
var newList = list.OrderBy(orderFunc); // 1, 2 ... 10
```

As another example consider a `Person` class:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Now you want to preserve a sort order that sorts by the `Name` property. In this case the `Func` operates on a `Person` type (`T`) and the `TResult` will be a string since `Name` is a string and is what you are sorting by.

```
Func<Person, string> nameOrder = p => p.Name;

var list = new List<Person>
{
    new Person { Id = 1, Name = "ABC" },
    new Person { Id = 2, Name = "DEF" },
    new Person { Id = 3, Name = "GHI" },
};

// descending order by name
foreach (var p in list.OrderByDescending(nameOrder))
    Console.WriteLine(p.Id + ":" + p.Name);

// 3:GHI
// 2:DEF
// 1:ABC

// re-assinging the list
list = new List<Person>
{
    new Person { Id = 23, Name = "Foo" },
    new Person { Id = 14, Name = "Buzz" },
    new Person { Id = 50, Name = "Bar" },
};

// reusing the order function (ascending by name in this case)
foreach (var p in list.OrderBy(nameOrder))
    Console.WriteLine(p.Id + ":" + p.Name);

// 50:Bar
// 14:Buzz
// 23:Foo
```

**EDIT:** be sure to add `ToList()` after the `OrderBy` calls **if** you need a `List<T>` since the LINQ methods will return an `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: What if the property can be anything?

Answer (score 1):

Calling `ToList()` or `ToArray()` on your `IEnumerable<T>` will cause it to be immediately evaluated. You can then assign the resulting list or array to "save" your ordered list.